# Serial communication using RS232C

Tags: gpio, serial

I am new to Raspberry Pi and `GPIO` communication, I am going to make a program to create a communication between my laptop and raspberry via serial com. After referred some tutorial, little confused about the connection between devices.
For my purpose, should I simply connect the `RX TX pin` with `COM` via 2 wires? or I need to add an `ADM232A` interface IC between these to make the conversion of `TTY` to `RS232C`.

BTW the program is using Qt serial.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use a serial connection if there is TCP/Ip and you are building both sides?

Comment: @Andy no special reason, just for learning and testing, accurately I want to read or write GIOP from another computer. Look like a monitor(my laptop) to make sure the program in Pi side is given the right IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi is 3V3 TTL (i.e. the signals are low=0V and high=3V3).  RS232 is +/- 12V (i.e. the signals are low=-12V and high=12V).  They do not mix.  Feeding that signal into a Pi GPIO will destroy both the GPIO and the Pi.

You need to use an appropriate adapter.

It may be simpler if you use USB at the Pi end.  At least you know the Pi will not be damaged by what's at the other end.

Comment: TTL is 5V not 3V3. Two references below, rest you can google. [Allaboutcircuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/logic-signal-voltage-levels/)

[Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels/ttl-logic-levels)

Comment: @ChetanBhargava 3V3 TTL is a well understood and commonly used expression.

Comment: please provide references

Answer (score 1):

### To connect your Raspberry pi to your laptop using USB to serial

1. Solder appropriate header to your Pi
   [image]
2. Get a USB to serial adapter that supports 3.3 Volt logic levels. 
   [image]
3. Get some dupont wires

[image: Dupont]

4. Use GPIO diagram below
   [image]
5. Connect your RxD GPIO Pin (GPIO15) to TxD pin of your USB to serial adapter. Connect TxD GPIO Pin (GPIO14) to RxD pin of your USB to serial adapter. Connect your USB to serial adapter ground to Raspberry Pi Ground (Pin 6 of GPIO connecter)
6. Use appropriate serial terminal program (depends on your OS and choice)